# Why Rotate div by mousemove not working javascript?

Tags: javascript, rotation, mousemove, mousedown, degrees

What I want is for the div to rotate from 0 to 360 without -. The rotation should go clockwise from 0 to 360 deg. In this code it ranges from 0 to 180 and from -180 to 0.

Second question: every time I click on "rotator div" my position changes ???

Code:

```js
document.getElementById("rotator").addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownRotator, false);


function mouseDownRotator(e) {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveRotator, true);
}

function mouseMoveRotator(e) {

  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpRotator, true);
  var arrow = document.getElementById("rotator");
  var arrowRects = document.getElementById("dragdiv").getBoundingClientRect();
  var center_x = (arrowRects.left) + (arrowRects.width / 2);
  var center_y = (arrowRects.top) + (arrowRects.height / 2);
  var mouse_x = e.pageX;
  var mouse_y = e.pageY;
  var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
  document.getElementById("dragdiv").style.transform = "rotate(" + (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90 + "deg)";
}

function mouseUpRotator() {
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveRotator, true);


}
```

```css
#dragdiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 250px;
}

#rotator {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid #4286f4;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: 43%;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="dragdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That code is going to add tons of events as you move the mouse

Comment: I copied from the source code to shorten it so there may be something I don't need. Welcome suggestions and change..